# Elasticsearch aggregation return null values as 0?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can count the hits per day that match my queried string with this code, but if the span of a whole week has no hits, then the query will return nothing - as opposed to returning 0 for each day. Is there a way I can 'default' to 0?

```
GET index/_search
    {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match_phrase": {
            "message": "Cannot login"
            }
          },
          {"range": {
            "@timestamp":{
              "gte":"2021-07-01",
              "lte":"2021-07-07"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this propose you need to add `extended_bounds` to your aggregation like below:

```
GET index/_search
    {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match_phrase": {
            "message": "Cannot login"
            }
          },
          {"range": {
            "@timestamp":{
              "gte":"2021-07-01",
              "lte":"2021-07-07"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "2021-07-01",
          "max": "2021-07-07"
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Please let me know if it did not solve your problem.

Comment: Yes friend! It does work, thanks for helping again

Comment: You're welcome, buddy. Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

When elasticsearch in aggregation response returns 0s means there are values not showed because of filters.

For example, I had a term filter on "region":"mexico" and it returned me:

- "colombia": 0
- "argentina": 0
- "mexico": 7

Firsts two because of they are in dataset (index) but filtered.

Hopin' it could help.